# How can I edit my .git/config file?

Tags: windows, git, heroku, git-remote

How can I edit my `.git/config` file?

Apparently, my `heroku` remote is set to something other than `heroku`; as a result, I am unable to properly deploy my Rails app on Heroku. However, I can't find how to edit it to set it to the right thing.

Where can I find the config file? I can't find a file named that way in my repository or in my Git folder installation. Where should I search for it and can I edit it?

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/pure-plateau-4958.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/pure-plateau-4958.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:vike27/sciencevest100.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:vike27/sciencevest100.git (push)
```

however heroku open doesn't work and heroku support says it is because of the previous afformentioned error in my .git/config file

I am on Windows8

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: What is the exact command you run to push to your `heroku` remote, and what error message do you get?

Comment: git push heroku master works. the things that doesnt work is heroku open.

Comment: @coderwannabe2 "Doesn't work" is too little information. Edit your question and add the exact message of that `heroku open` error.

Answer (score 5):

Your remotes are usually set in your local config file.
The file can be found end edited here: `.git/config`.
You can edit that directly or use the `git config` config to set/get entries in it.

`git help config` for details.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I edit my `.git/config` file?

Don't, unless you know exactly what you're doing. To modify your Git config, you should instead strive to use Git commands only. One reason for avoiding to edit the config file manually is that you may end up corrupting it inadvertently.

> Apparently, my `heroku` remote is set to something other than `heroku` [...]

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to change the URL associated with the remote called `heroku`. First, check what the URL currently used is, by running

```
git remote -v
```

This command should list the `fetch` and `push` URLs associated with the remote `heroku`. If you find that those URLs are indeed incorrect, then run

```
git remote set-url heroku <new-url>
```

to set the URL of your `heroku` remote to `<new-url>`.

Comment: When I type git remote set-url heroku <new-url> I get:   sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: I updated question with more details do you know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Is <new-url> supposed to be explicitly that or is it a placeholder for something else I am supposed to substitute when running on my machine?

Comment: @coderwannabe2 Of course, `<new-url>` is a placeholder for the URL that you're `heroku` remote should be.